# Conditionally (depending on duration) show an activity indicator during UI activity in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiscrollview, uiactivityindicatorview

I use a UIScrollView to display a PDF file. Scrolling horizontally changes the page. This works fine, but when the next page is a full sized image, the scrollview stucks before starting to animate the scrolling. This is normal behavior.

I want to display an activity indicator when the duration exceeds e.g. one second to improve the feedback to the user.

I have already tried the naive way of starting a timer that starts the indicator after one second. It does not show up, I assume that it is queued on the same thread as the UI activity (changing the page) that takes so long. I also tried to use performSelectorOnMainThread for starting the indicator but that was a weak guess and did not help.

My understanding of the threading in iOS is the problem here. I can only guess, that I have to interrupt the page change, execute the start of the activity indicator, and then go on changing (rendering) the page. I have no idea how to do that. I´d appreciate one.

Comment: Probably the loading of the image is happening on the main thread, so it blocks your UI. You should try to do the loading on a different queue than the main one, and then display your activity indicator. Then, when your image finishes loading, you stop the activity indicator and update your scroll view accordingly.

Comment: You are right, the image loading does happen on the main thread. I just moved it to a background thread for testing. Unfortunately this also changes the scrolling behavior: It does scroll immediately to a white page now and as soon the image is ready it is displayed. I´d rather have the old behavior: The ScrollView stucks a little bit, but when scrolling happens, the next page is already there. That avoids this annoying flicker to white in between.

Comment: ...and when this "stuck" takes too long, I want to display the activity indicator. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your timer does not fire because you are using the default run loop mode when calling the `performSelectorOnMainThread` method or scheduling the `NSTimer`. It does not work because  in that case your method will be called after the scroll finishes, i.e. after you release the finger.

To make your timer fire even during scrolling use `NSRunLoopCommonModes` as the run loop mode.

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(yourMethod)
                       withObject:nil
                    waitUntilDone:NO
                            modes:@[NSRunLoopCommonModes]];
```

**EDIT**

You should not block the main thread otherwise the method will not be called until the main thread finishes loading the image. Instead load the image in a background thread and prevent the scroll view from scrolling by implementing a delegate method.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
  if([self isLoadingImage]){
    //save the content offset when you start loading the image
    //and use it here to stop scroll view from scrolling.
    scrollView.contentOffset = offsetWhenLoadingStarted;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have just tried your proposal, but as the image loading is also done on the main thread, the timer event is still too late. However, it seems to be a little faster than before. It fires when the scrollview is scrolling, but not during the scrollview being stuck. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I see. You cannot achieve what you want if you block the main thread. I have edited the answer and added how you can prevent the scroll view from scrolling without blocking the main thread.

Comment: Thats kind of a workaround but I don´t think that there is a more straight forward way to do it. Thank you.